# SpaceX Dragon Shape: Power Series, Ellipsoid, or Haack/Von Karman?

Tags: spacex, rockets, falcon-9, dragon, nosecone

The SpaceX Dragon module has a round apex typical of power series, ellipsoid, and Haack/Von Karman shapes. I'm wondering which of these SpaceX actually used. References would be appreciated.

My guess is it's a Haack/Von Karman shape, because these are specifically optimized for less drag. If it's in fact a Haack or Von Karman shape, then which of these is it? (Von Karman shapes are a subset of Haack shapes, and Haack shapes come in various other types).

Thanks!!